# how to hide lint error messages in vscode but not squiggly lines

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I turn off VSCode displaying the error message with a red shaded background for the whole line?

[image]

I still want the red squiggly line, which lets me hover over the error to get more info:

[image]

In summary:

**Yes**: Red Squiggly Line with hover pop up

**No**: Red line background, red error message

This is for a Go project, but I noticed it does the same thing for JSON files.

Comment: thats not default behavior. You have some extension configured to do that. At least mine doesnt look like this. Maybe its also a newish build in setting which you can enable. You can maybe see where its comming from when you check the problems pane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have installed [error lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens).

Try to run command `errorLens.toggleError` to disable or enable it.